# Converting multiple radar files with Py-ART

Tags: python

So, i'm trying to write a script to convert multiple radar files in a directory using Py-ART.

```
import sys
import glob
import os.path
import pyart

list_of_files = glob.glob('*.mvol')

for file in list_of_files:
    print(file)

    radar = pyart.aux_io.read_gamic(file)

    pyart.io.write_cfradial( file + '.nc' , radar, format='NETCDF4')
```

The code actually works, but instead of converting multiple files, it just converts the first one.

I know it's an issue with the loop but i don't know what I'm missing.

Comment: Just for sanity, you confirmed there is more than one file in your list_of_files?

Comment: Well, when i run:

for file in list_of_files:
    print(file)

i jus gives me the first file as the output.

Comment: What do you get if you do print(len(list_of_files)) ?

Comment: It gives the number of files as 144